# Acro package: Add constant text to short form in acronym list?

Tags: acro

I've written a report using the `acro` package.  It was reviewed for compliance with organizational standards.  In the list of abbreviations at the end, I have to precede each acronym with "(U)".  Is there an easy way to do this?

For example, on the first occurrence, I  want "read-only memory (ROM)" in the main body, but I want "`\textbf{(U) ROM} read only memory`" in the list of abbreviations at the end of a report.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) demonstrating your set-up.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that the MWEs were for clarifying the situation, but it's clear now that it also saves answerers a lot of time.  I would add an MWE, but clemens already provided one in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{rom}{
  short = ROM,
  long = read-only memory,
}

\newcommand*\mylistformat[1]{(\textbf{U}) #1}

\acsetup{
  list-short-format = \mylistformat
}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum \ac{rom}. Long: \acl{rom}. Short: \acs{rom}.

\printacronyms

\end{document}
```

[image]

(The extra boldface around the `(U)` isn't visible because the default list is built as `description` list where items are bold, anyway…)

Comment: Thanks, clemens! Your answer drills down under the hood in the sense that the *mylistformat* command doesn't seem to show up in the *ACRO* documentation.  That's fine, it works. From experimentation, I found that if I decided that I don't want bold in the prefixing "(U)", I use `\newcommand*\mylistformat[1]{\normalfont{(U)} \textbf{#1}}`.

Comment: Well, the _new_ in `\newcommand` tells that it defines a previously undefined command. `\mylistformat` doesn't exist in `acro`. It is a random command name I came up with for the sake of this answer.

Comment: Of course! Thanks for straightening me out on that. The documentation's example for `list-short-format` is `\scshape`, which googling reveals as a command put between curly braces, along with text that it should apply to. Your example above of a command that takes an argument reveals how `list-sort-format` can be more flexibly used.